# Display a specified div by id which is relative to row variable on button click in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page that shows rows from database and every row has a hidden form to edit it . i wanted to show the form of the choosed row on button click with javascript, i tried all possibilities i know and i searched for (like array for getElementbyID, onclick inside for loop ... etc ) .
In other attempts : it worked but every button displayed only one form, either the first or the last, which is not the target .

Here's the important from my code :

```
while($row_publications=$result_publications->fetch_assoc()){
$counter++ ;
echo "<h3>".$counter.") ".$row_publications['title']." :</h3><br/>";
echo "<button id='display_button_".$counter."' onclick=\'display_edit_form(".$counter.");\'>Edit</button>
<div id='edit_form_".$counter."' style='display:none;'>";
//the form 
echo "</div>";

//Here's my last try in javascript i tested it manually for 2 rows :
<script>
var i = 0;
var counter= <?php echo $counter; ?> ;

var element = ["empty","edit_form_1","edit_form_2"];
var display_buttons = ["empty","display_button_1","display_button_2"];

for(i=1;i<=counter;i++){
document.getElementById(display_buttons[i]).onclick= function myfunction(){ display_edit_form(i); };
}

//I tried also another variable v=i and same undefined parameter problem on call


function display_edit_form(i){
alert("i="+element[i]); // this alerts : i=undefined
if (document.getElementById(element[i]).style.display === "none") {

  document.getElementById(element[i]).style.display = "block";
} else {

  document.getElementById(element[i]).style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: look this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Comment: @threeside Thanks bro this W3 tutorial solved my problem (it uses classes instead of ids and nextElementSibling to show next element) thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use ID attributes in a loop - it gets overly complicated. Instead you can use `sibling` selectors - once you have identified the relationship between elements (in this case between the button and the DIV element - relation is essentially nextSibling ) you can invoke it with quite simple syntax.

The below creates a mockup of "the important part of your code" - the loop in this case just generates 10 elements with hidden forms. Notice that all of the ID attributes have been removed and the inline event handler has been put in the HEAD section as an external event listener.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Targeting sibling element</title>
        <script>
            /*
                wait for the DOM to load and then find all buttons
                that are to be used for triggering the display of the hidden
                forms.
            */
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
                Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('button.edit') ).forEach( bttn=>{
                    /*
                        iterate through the nodelist collection and assign a `click` event handler
                        to each button.
                    */
                    bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                        let div=this.nextElementSibling;
                        div.style.display = div.style.display=='block' ? 'none' : 'block';
                    })
                });         
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

            for( $i=1; $i <= 10; $i++ ){
                printf(
                    '<h3>Counter: %1$d) Publication Title: %1$d :</h3>
                    <br />
                    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                    <div style="display:none;">
                        <form>
                            <!-- other content -->
                            <h1>Form #%1$d</h1>
                        </form>
                    </div>',
                    $i
                );
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
  Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('button.edit') ).forEach( bttn=>{
    bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      let div=this.nextElementSibling;
      div.style.display = div.style.display=='block' ? 'none' : 'block';
    })
  });   
});
```

```html
<h3>Counter: 1) Publication Title: 1 :</h3>
<br />
<button class="edit">Edit</button>
<div style="display:none;">
  <form>
    <!-- other content -->
    <h1>Form #1</h1>
  </form>
</div>

<h3>Counter: 2) Publication Title: 2 :</h3>
<br />
<button class="edit">Edit</button>
<div style="display:none;">
  <form>
    <!-- other content -->
    <h1>Form #2</h1>
  </form>
</div>
```